# Why does Deezer default to French (or just does not show in the original language)

Tags: localization, deezer

I have used http://www.deezer.com/ for a while now and it has always been in English. Recently it is showing everything in French. Google Chrome will auto-translate pretty OK but why is Deezer suddenly French?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the language in settings was set to French. Don't remember ever setting that and not sure why I would but there you go.

Go to 'Cog' (top right) > Settings

[image]

Then select your preferred language > Save

[image]

Also refer here for Chrome settings

[Why does the internet think I'm French?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23040/why-does-the-internet-think-im-french)